# On opening keyboard the content doesn't get pushed up

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield

I got 6 `TextFormField` on registering user page,when I click to input some text,the keyboard opens,but the content doesn't get pushed up,so I'm unable to  see what I'm writing in textbox.
I want the content to be pushed.
Please help!

here is the code:

```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Register"),
    ),
    body: Card(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Form(
        autovalidate: _autoValidate,
        key: formKey,
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Username"),
              validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                  ? '3 or more char'
                  : null,
              onSaved: (input) => globals.userName = input,
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Password"),
              validator: (input) => input.length < 8
                  ? 'min 8 char'
                  : null,
              onSaved: (input) => globals.passWord = input,
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Firstname"),
              validator: (input) =>
                  input.length <= 1 ? 'Input your name' : null,
              onSaved: (input) => globals.firstName = input,
            ), //First Name TextBox
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Lastname"),
              validator: (input) =>
                  input.length <= 1 ? 'Input your last name' : null,
              onSaved: (input) => globals.lastName = input,
            ), //Last Name TextBox
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
              onSaved: (input) => globals.eMail = input,
              validator: _validateEmail,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Phone"),
              validator: (input) =>
                  input.length != 10 ? 'Input your phone' : null,
              onSaved: (input) => globals.pHone = input,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: _submit,
                      child: Text("Registruj se"),
                    ) //Submit Button

                    ),
                _showErrorMessage(),
              ],
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried without `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,`

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true` should allow it to scroll. `false` prevents the `TextField` from scrolling into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` from Scaffold fixed this issue.